# Apply a style on a EditTextView in android

Tags: android, android-styles

i am trying to specify and set a style for a specific android view component in which this case is a EditText.

here is the style i am trying to apply a global set of styles

```
 <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/lightBlue</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dip</item>
</style>


<style name="ActivityStyleYellow">
    <item name="android:background">@color/brightYellow</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/textViewYellow</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:text">@style/editTextYellow</item>

</style>

 <style name="ActivityStyleBlue">
    <item name="android:background">@color/lightBlue</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/textViewBlue</item>
    <item name="android:EditTextViewStyle">@style/editTextBlue</item>
</style>
```

And here is the styles for my view components on a seperate xml file

```
 <style name="textViewBlue" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkBlue</item>
              <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/text_padding</item>
        </style>

        <style name="textViewYellow" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkYellow</item>
              <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/text_padding</item>
        </style>

        <style name="editTextBlue" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
            <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/text_padding</item>
            <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkBlue</item>
        </style>

     <style name="editTextYellow" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/text_padding</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkYellow</item>
    </style>
```

The issue is this line:   @style/editTextYellow

android:EditTextViewStyle doesnt exist and i cant find any reference to it. i assumed it will be that because i also assumed what the textViewStyle was and that worked.

i couuld not find a define list of what android:xxx styles are valid but i suppose editText should surely be?

Is there a list to show what components i can use for "android:xxx"? i basically want to apply to a particular View component type.

is this possible for editText?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is android:editTextStyle. For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.EditText</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.EditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_font_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/default_grey</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Do u know where i can find a list of android view style items that are valid?

Comment: Ok, this might be a backwards way to do it, but the way I found this (and other attributes used to style different ui elements for the whole app, since this is quite useful) is by looking [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) and searching for the word 'style'...